# PHP: Parse xml and check file has content beyond header

Tags: php, xml

I have tried to look this up online before posting here and can't seem to find the answer I'm looking for. I've been exploring XML parsing and have been making steady progress but I've hit a stumbling block. What I'm trying to do is check if the XML from a feed has any content beyond the header (in this case, the header to the XML is just: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`). If the feed has content, I can do everything I need to do (whether that's displaying it or populating a database with the results) BUT when the feed is unavailable, the resulting XML document only displays the header and nothing else.

So, what I want to be able to do is to check if the XML document has anything after the header and, if so, update the locally saved XML file and, if not, display an error and not overwrite the content of the local file.

The original code I had was:

```
$acc = new DOMDocument();
$acc->load(url for xml file here);

$acc->save(filepath to saved xml here);
$filepath = (same filepath to use as check);

if((is_file($filepath))&&(file_exists($filepath))){
    echo "XML Data successfully written to directory.";
}else{
    echo "XML data has failed to be written to the directory.";
}
```

..but obviously this just checks if the file exists, not that there's any meaningful content in it. If the XML server is offline/unavailable, it still outputs XML files but with just the header. So I tried this:

```
$acc = new DOMDocument();
$acc->load(XML URL);

if(!empty($acc)){//so, something came in from the xml server 
    if(is_null($acc){//Is it empty?
        echo"Server unavailable, try later.";
    }else{
        $acc->save(filepath to saved XML);
        $filepath = (same filepath to use as check check);
        if((is_file($filepath))&&(file_exists($filepath))){
            echo "XML Data successfully written to directory.";
        }else{
            echo "XML data has failed to be written to the directory.";
        }
    }
}else{
    echo"XML server unavailable for request at present";
}
```

..but no joy. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated... I know I'm doing something wrong, but would really appreciate any pointers...

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2):

The DOMDocument class will not load the XML if it is invalid - either because the server returns a 404 or similar, or because there was no XML content. It returns false and also outputs a warning in either case.

If you're happy seeing the warning in your error logs, and you don't need to distinguish between server error and your "empty" XML file, you can simply do:

```
$acc = new DOMDocument();
if ($acc->load("35702954.xml")) {
    $acc->save($filepath);
    if(is_file($filepath)){
        echo "XML Data successfully written to directory.";
    }else{
        echo "XML data has failed to be written to the directory.";
    }
}else{
    echo"XML server unavailable for request at present";
}
```

`file_exists` is redundant because `is_file` already checks whether the file exists.

Comment: The XML appears to be valid as the server does not return a 404. It's just that when the server is not outputting what it normally does, it just outputs an xml file with the xml header which passes through and overwrites the exisitng (full of content) xml file... Is there a way of checking for content beyond the header and rejecting the xml file if there's nothing? At least, a solution that doesn't require extensive coding! (although I'd be happy to code it if that is what's required...) 

I've edited to remove the redundant file_exists -so thanks for that tip :)

Comment: The DOMDocument `load` method will also return `false` in this case. The code above worked in my testing for an XML "file" with just a header.

Comment: I'll try it with a local mockup -it may have just been 'one of those things'... Thanks for the replies, most helpful :)